# How to delete a particular array in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a document in which i store details in array and i increment the same array with on update as well,here is my record can anyone suggest help please,

I want to delete first array i more info
[image]

Comment: Where is the document you are talking about? Please don't post an image as you  are trying to do.

Comment: You want to delete fist element of the array? array[0] is it?

Comment: db.more_info.drop()!

Comment: @codePhobia exactly.......

Comment: Are you using node mongodb native driver or mongoose? reconfirming

Comment: As I understand `more_info` is a collection, so if you want to remove the `[0]` you probably want to know the `_id` to do `YourModel.remove({ '_id': ObjectId("idstring") })`

Comment: mongoose...............

Answer (score 0):

if you want to remove the first element of more_info array use the following mongoose code.

```
 var query = {
    _id : // your objectId
  };
  var update = {
    $pop: {more_info: -1}
  };
  models.CollectionName.findOneAndUpdate(query,update,function (err,data) {
 if(err){
      // error
    }
 else {
     console.log('data ',data)
   }
})
```

Here go through the docs to know more about array update operators
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pop/